# Error al recuperar registro de la BD en la capa de Datos para usarlos en un ActionResult dentro del Controlador ASP . Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, controller, http-post

Estoy realizando un sistema de facturación en **ASP .Net MVC** de 3 capas. Sólo me falta grabar el detalle de la venta, porque la venta ya me inserta. En el caso del detalle extraigo todos los campos que se requieren para insertar el detalle, excepto el código de venta que es autogenerado (Ejemplo: 'V001').

Por eso quiero hacer un `select top (1) * from VENTAS` y de eso extraerle la 'V' y los ceros(0) para sumarle 1. Entonces quedaría V001>---1(+1)>V002.

¿Se podría hacer algo así o habrá conflicto?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GuardarVenta(string RUC,double VEN_TOT,List<VentadetaEntity>ListadoDetalles)
    {
        VentaEntity x = new VentaEntity();
        x.RUC = RUC.Trim();
        x.VEN_TOT = VEN_TOT;
        ViewBag.mensaje = venta.agregarVentaBL(x);

        VentaEntity a = venta.ultimaVentaBL();
        //a.VEN_COD;



        //VentadetaEntity y = new VentadetaEntity();
        //y.VEN_COD = "V003";

        foreach (var item in ListadoDetalles)
        {
            VentadetaEntity d = new VentadetaEntity();

            d.VEN_COD = a.VEN_COD;
            //d.VEN_COD = "V003";
            d.PROD_COD = int.Parse(item.PROD_COD.ToString());
            d.DET_CANT = int.Parse(item.DET_CANT.ToString());
            d.DET_PRE = double.Parse(item.DET_PRE.ToString());

            ViewBag.mensaje = venta.agregarVentadetaBL(d);


            //VentadetaEntity d = new VentadetaEntity("V003",PROD_COD,DET_CANT,DET_PRE);
        }

        //y.PROD_COD = int.Parse(PROD_COD);
        //y.DET_CANT = DET_CANT;
        //y.DET_PRE = DET_PRE;

        //ViewBag.mensaje = venta.agregarVentadetaBL(y);

        return Json(true);

        //return RedirectToAction("ListarCliente");

    }
```

Capa de Datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente,cuando le doy guardar me salta el error que no encuentra datos ¿por qué?

Comment: `select top (1) * from VENTAS` esta sentencia no te asegura que te devuelva el ultimo valor y si a partir de los datos traídos de esta sentencia intentas generar el siguiente código de venta este podrá estar repetido

Answer (score 0):

`select top (1) * from VENTAS` esta sentencia no te asegura que te devuelva el ultimo valor y si a partir de los datos traídos de esta sentencia intentas generar el siguiente código de venta este podrá estar repetido y te podrá causar errores según tengas diseñada la tabla.

Por otra parte, el error lo tienes en que no lees el `SqlDataReader`. Para poder tener acceso a los datos que este contiene debes "leer" ese reader, para ello puedes usar el método `bool Read()` del `SQLDataReader` el cual avanzará una "fila" si este no ha llegado al final de estas.

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteREader();

while(dr.Read())//Avanza a la siguiente fila si existe y devuelve true en caso de que avance
{
    //Ahora si podríamos leer los datos de la fila actual
    dr["VEN_COD"].ToString();
}
```

De todas maneras, para tu caso en concreto si lo quieres leer la primera fila te recomiendo que uses el método `bool NextResult()`:

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteREader();

if(dr.NextResult())//Avanza a la siguiente fila si existe y devuelve true en caso de que avance
{
    //Ahora si podríamos leer los datos de la fila actual
    dr["VEN_COD"].ToString();
}
```